# Use $this->Paginator->sort sort by a field not in the related model

Tags: sorting, cakephp, paginator

I want to use $this->Paginator->sort to generate a link, but sorted by a field not in the current table, which related to this table. So can I do that? and how to do that?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an external field on sort, you can do so like:

```
<th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('ExternalModelName', 'ExternalModelName.fieldname'); ?></th>
```

But the model relationship must also be correct. So assuming your relationship is setup correctly, the above will work.

Comment: Not working for me. A `User` can "BelongsTo" a `Company`. The `debug()` from the result of the `paginate()` from the controller in the view shows a `['User']` array on the same "level" as the `['Company']` one by I can't order the `paginate()` result by `Company.name`. Cheers.